# Why does $\mathrm{Rank}(A{A^*} - {A^*}A) \ne 1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $A \in M_n$, why does $\mathrm{Rank}(A{A^*} - {A^*}A) \neq 1$?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Hint.

Observe that

$$
\mathrm{Trace}(AA^*)=\mathrm{Trace}(A^*A),
$$
and hence
$$
\mathrm{Trace}(AA^*-A^*A)=0.
$$
Next show that, if $B$ is diagonalizable and $\mathrm{Rank}(B)=1$, then $\mathrm{Trace}(B)\ne 0$.

Finally, observe that $AA^*-A^*A$ is hermitian and hence diagonalizable.

Comment: I don't think the last part is really that relevant. It seems to me that the relevant detail is that the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues, so if only one is nonzero then the trace can't be zero. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: Last line you meant Trace(B) not equal to 0, not 1.

Comment: The final conclusion requires some more information about $B$, e.g. it is Hermetian, thus diagonalizable.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, let $M\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ s.t. $rank(M)=1,tr(M)=0$. Then $M$ is similar to $diag(\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix},0_{n-2})$.

Proof: According to Jordan theory, $rank(M)=1$ implies that $M$ is similar to $diag(\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix},0_{n-2})$ or to $diag(a,0_{n-1})$ where $a\not= 0$. Since $tr(M)=0$, the second case is impossible.